# React not attaching event listeners

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

**UPDATE:** Something about removing the `output` entry from the webpack configuration allows React event listeners to function properly.

---

I'm working on a React/TypeScript app and hand-rolling the webpack configuration by hand for the first time.

For some reason it appears that, while all the React rendering behavior is working as expected, none of the event listeners are being attached to the React components.

I'm pretty stumped at this point, and searching around the web I'm not seeing anyone running into similar issues.

My webpack setup is pretty simple and rudimentary and seems to follow guides laid out by both webpack, as well as what articles describe as being appropriate.

The only semi-unusual behavior I have in my project is using the `TsConfigPathsPlugin` plugin to resolve path aliases.

For reference, everything compiles successfully for both the build and dev server and renders correctly and as expected (similarly, the path alias resolution is clearly working). There are no errors or warnings thrown either at build-time or runtime.

**Small Possible Clue:** I did notice that the webpack dev server logs out "Live Reloading enabled" twice, and the React dev tools for chrome identify two instances of the single component rendered to the page.

Below, I've listed the components being included in the small app as well as the build configuration. Let me know if any other files would be useful to see.

**index.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

import { ENTRY_ELEMENT_ID } from './configs'

import Test from '~ui/app/Test'

render(
    <Test />,
    document.querySelector(`#${ENTRY_ELEMENT_ID}`)
)
```

**Test.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'

function Test() {
    return (
        <button onClick={() => { console.log('Clicked!') }}>Test</button>
    )
}

export default Test
```

*To be clear, this onClick event never executes*

**webpack.common.js**

```js
const { TsConfigPathsPlugin } = require('awesome-typescript-loader')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
        plugins: [
            new TsConfigPathsPlugin()
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin()
    ]
}
```

**webpack.ui.dev.js**

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common')

const { DISTRIBUTION_ROOT, UI_ROOT } = require('./path-helpers')

module.exports = merge(commonConfig, {
    entry: `${UI_ROOT}/index.tsx`,
    output: {
        path: `${DISTRIBUTION_ROOT}/ui`,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: `${UI_ROOT}/index.html`
        })
    ]
})
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "target": "ES5",
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~ui/*": ["apps/ui/*"],
            "~script/*": ["apps/script/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "./apps/"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

Comment: why do you think that it is related to webpack?

Comment: That's a good question, I think it's more that the React app itself is so simple I can't totally think of what else there could be other than the build process. You think there might be other things I'm overlooking as far as suspects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the answer is silly, as expected. One tutorial I read at some point included in the root HTML file:

```html
<script defer="defer" src="bundle.js"></script>
```

When combined with `HtmlWebpackPlugin` this loads the app twice, and something about this causes conflicts with React's system for event listeners.

Shout to [felixmosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6539317/felixmosh) for suspecting this issue was not reflective of an issue with the build configuration.